# Function tukey.add.test (asbio) with other package

Tags: r, anova, asbio

usually I use the tukey.add.test from the asbio package in order to check interaction between treatmest and block in ANOVA RCBD, the package is now archived so I can no longer use this function or anything from the package.

You guys know another function to check this interaction? Any suggestion?

Comment: Can you provide some sample data? Provided I haven't misunderstood, this should be possible with e.g. `TukeyHSD`. Providing sample data and details involving your expected output would also be helpful in avoiding the "R package request" red flag of topics that are off-topic here on Stack Overflow ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done, the agricolae::nonadditivity function does the same test with the exactly same p.values.